# Verify OpenPGP based RSA signature with WinCrypt/CryptoAPI

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, cryptoapi, mscapi

I have code that parses OpenPGP packets and I have `n`, `e` of the public key packet as well as `s` of the signature packet as byte arrays.

In order to verify a signature I first initialize `CryptAcquireContext` (I also tried with `PROV_RSA_FULL` instead of `PROV_RSA_AES`)

```
HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, nullptr, nullptr, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
```

then create a hash

```
HCRYPTHASH hHash;
CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash); // as the digest algorithm of the signature was 2 => SHA1
```

and populate it using `CryptHashData`. This works so far as well as parsing and importing the public key using `CryptImportKey`.

```
typedef struct _RSAKEY
{
    BLOBHEADER blobheader;
    RSAPUBKEY rsapubkey;
    BYTE n[4096 / 8];
} RSAKEY;

static int verify_signature_rsa(HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv, HCRYPTHASH hHash, public_key_t &p_pkey, signature_packet_t &p_sig)
{
    int i_n_len = mpi_len(p_pkey.key.sig.rsa.n); // = 512; p_pkey.key.sig.rsa.n is of type uint8_t n[2 + 4096 / 8];
    int i_s_len = mpi_len(p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s); // = 256; p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s is of type uint8_t s[2 + 4096 / 8]

    HCRYPTKEY hPubKey;
    RSAKEY rsakey;
    rsakey.blobheader.bType = PUBLICKEYBLOB; // 0x06
    rsakey.blobheader.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION; // 0x02
    rsakey.blobheader.reserved = 0;
    rsakey.blobheader.aiKeyAlg = CALG_RSA_KEYX;
    rsakey.rsapubkey.magic = 0x31415352;// ASCII for RSA1
    rsakey.rsapubkey.bitlen = i_n_len * 8; // = 4096
    rsakey.rsapubkey.pubexp = 65537;

    memcpy(rsakey.n, p_pkey.key.sig.rsa.n + 2, i_n_len); // skip first two byte which are MPI length
    std::reverse(rsakey.n, rsakey.n + i_n_len); // need to convert to little endian for WinCrypt

    CryptImportKey(hCryptProv, (BYTE*)&rsakey, sizeof(BLOBHEADER) + sizeof(RSAPUBKEY) + i_n_len, 0, 0, &hPubKey); // no error

    std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> pSig(new BYTE[i_s_len]);
    memcpy(pSig.get(), p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s + 2, i_s_len); // skip first two byte which are MPI length
    std::reverse(p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s, p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s + i_s_len); // need to convert to little endian for WinCrypt

    if (!CryptVerifySignature(hHash, pSig.get(), i_s_len, hPubKey, nullptr, 0))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError(); // err=2148073478 -> INVALID_SIGNATURE
        CryptDestroyKey(hPubKey);
        return -1;
    }

    CryptDestroyKey(hPubKey);
    return 0;
}
```

`CryptVerifySignature` fails with `GetLastError()` decoding to `INVALID_SIGNATURE`.

On https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.2 I read

```
With RSA signatures, the hash value is encoded using PKCS#1 encoding
type EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 as described in Section 9.2 of RFC 3447.  This
requires inserting the hash value as an octet string into an ASN.1
structure.
```

Is that needed or is that automatically done by `CryptVerifySignature`? If not, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in this line

```
std::reverse(p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s, p_sig.algo_specific.rsa.s + i_s_len); // need to convert to little endian for WinCrypt
```

which should read

```
std::reverse(pSig.get(), pSig.get() + i_s_len); // need to convert to little endian for WinCrypt
```

because converting the source of the bytes from big to little endian does not convert another buffer after a copy.

Answer (score 2):

The PKCS#1 padding is not likely to be the problem. The hint that it uses an OID for the hash algorithm by default is pointing to PKCS#1 v1.5 type of signatures, so I think you can rest assured that the right padding is used.

More confirmation can be found in the [`CryptSignHash` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> By default, the Microsoft RSA providers use the PKCS #1 padding method for the signature. The hash OID in the DigestInfo element of the signature is automatically set to the algorithm OID associated with the hash object. Using the CRYPT_NOHASHOID flag will cause this OID to be omitted from the signature.

---

Looking through the API documentation, the following caught my eye:

> The native cryptography API uses little-endian byte order while the .NET Framework API uses big-endian byte order. If you are verifying a signature generated by using a .NET Framework API, you must swap the order of signature bytes before calling the CryptVerifySignature function to verify the signature.

This does mean that the API is not PKCS#1 v1.5 compliant as the byte order is explicitly specified therein. This is therefore certainly something to be aware of and could be part of a solution.

Comment: The .NET is slightly better, but I cannot see how a company can get away with such bad API documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your efford. The error was caused by a typo and the place where you supposed it...

Comment: What do you mean with "where I supposed it?", was it to do with big/little endian?

Comment: See the answer I provided. My (stupid) error was in the endianess conversion.

Comment: Ah, OK, you did do endianess conversion, but it returned the wrong result, should have read on :) Glad you got it solved.